# What is this SQL IF doing with the Ampersand?

Tags: sql

What is this SQL IF doing with the Ampersand?

```
IF ((@TablesToDeleteFrom & 1) <> 0 AND
            (@TablesToDeleteFrom & 2) <> 0 AND
            (@TablesToDeleteFrom & 4) <> 0 AND
            (@TablesToDeleteFrom & 8) <> 0 AND
            (EXISTS (SELECT UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE @UserId = UserId)))
        BEGIN
    ...
```

This is from the aspnet mebership DB, inside the aspnet_Users_DeleteUser SP.  The @TablesToDeleteFrom is declared as an int and defaulted to 0.  I have not seen the use of the & like this before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [& operator in a SQL Server WHERE Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670230/operator-in-a-sql-server-where-clause)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [bitwise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx) operator. Basically Tables to delete from will store multiple tables in a single integer based field by creating a bitwise combination of values for tables. Here is an example.

```
1 - TableA
2 - TableB
4 - TableC
8 - TableD
```

TableA & TableB = 1 | 2 = 3. (You use the OR operator to get the result, and the AND operator to check for a result). So the value of 3 gets stored in the field. You can then use the ampersand operator to see if the value was set. 1 & 3 == 1, so TableA would be deleted. 4 & 3 = 0 so TableC would not be deleted.

Comment: Aaargh!  Can't believe I dodn't see that!  Thanks Bob.

Comment: No problem, its obvious if you use it a lot, but it isn't that common.

Answer (score 5):

As @Bob says, `&` is bitwise and; and so, by the way, a more compact equivalent of

```
IF ((@TablesToDeleteFrom & 1) <> 0 AND
            (@TablesToDeleteFrom & 2) <> 0 AND
            (@TablesToDeleteFrom & 4) <> 0 AND
            (@TablesToDeleteFrom & 8) <> 0 AND
```

is

```
IF ((@TablesToDeleteFrom & 15) = 15) AND
```