# What is the use of "&" operator in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the use of & operator in the code specified below. IS there any benefit of using & instead of "AND". Please elaborate.

```
CASE ( C.[Status] & F.[Status] & D.[Status] & DWT.[Status] & P.[Status] )
    WHEN 1
        THEN CASE ( C.IsDeleted & F.IsDeleted & D.IsDeleted & P.IsDeleted )
        WHEN 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE 7
        END
    ELSE 6
END
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [& operator in a SQL Server WHERE Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670230/operator-in-a-sql-server-where-clause)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`&` is bit AND operation:

- `&`  Bitwise AND
- `|`  Bitwise OR
- `^` Bitwise exclusive OR
- `~`  Bitwise NOT

Comment: what is its use as compared to logical AND ?

Comment: Pakhanstov: Did you miss the last '8' in the link?
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1218

Comment: @Geert Immerzeel Thanks for corrections, yes I meant tip=1218

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise AND operation, take a look at [& (Bitwise AND) (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx) in Books On Line

Answer (score 0):

It's a bitwise operator - AND

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx