# The data types varchar(max) and varchar(max) are incompatible in the '&' operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a `sp_send_dbmail` that uses HTML formatting that will send two different tables within 1 email. But I keep getting:

> The data types varchar(max) and varchar(max) are incompatible in the '&' operator

This script is pulling info from 2 different Views that populate the 2 different tables.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @MTDResults varchar(max)

SET @MTDResults = 
N'<style type="text/css">
#box-table
{
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-top: 7px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 7px solid #9baff1;
}
#box-table th
{
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: Bold;
background: #b9c9fe;
border-right: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-left: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 2px solid #9baff1;
color: #039;
}
#box-table td
{
border-right: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-left: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-bottom: 1px solid #aabcfe;
color: #669;
}
tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even)   { background-color:#fff; } 
</style>'+  
N'<H1><font color="Black">MTD Results</H1>'+
N'<table id="box-table">'+
N'<tr><font color = "Black">
<th> Type </th>
<th> Sales </th>
<th> Cost </th>
<th> Margin </th>
<th> Percentage </th>
<th> Tons </th>
</tr>'
+ CAST ( (
Select 
TD = Type,'', 
TD = Sales,'', 
TD = Cost,'', 
TD = Marg,'', 
TD = Tons
from [dbo].[Daily_Sales_MTD_HTML] 
FOR XML PATH ('tr')
) as varchar(max))
+ '</table>'

DECLARE @Top10CustMTD varchar(max)

SET @Top10CustMTD = 
N'<style type="text/css">
#box-table
{
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-top: 7px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 7px solid #9baff1;
}
#box-table th
{
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: Bold;
background: #b9c9fe;
border-right: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-left: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 2px solid #9baff1;
color: #039;
}
#box-table td
{
border-right: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-left: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-bottom: 1px solid #aabcfe;
color: #669;
}
tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even)   { background-color:#fff; } 
</style>'+  
N'<H1><font color="Black">Top 10 Customers For the Month</H1>'+
N'<table id="box-table">'+
N'<tr><font color = "Black">
<th> Customer Name </th>
<th> Sales </th>
<th> Margin </th>
<th> Percentage </th>
</tr>'
+ CAST ( (
Select 
TD = Custname,'',
TD = Sales,'',
TD = Margin,'',
TD = Perc,''
from [dbo].[Daily_Sales_10CustMTD_HTML]
FOR XML PATH ('tr')
) as varchar(max))
+ '</table>'

DECLARE @Mergedtable NVARCHAR(max)
set @Mergedtable = @MTDResults & @Top10CustMTD

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@recipients = 'JSmith@email.com',
@copy_recipients = '', 
@subject = 'Daily Sales',
@body = @Mergedtable,
@body_format = 'html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `set @Mergedtable = @MTDResults & @Top10CustMTD` to `set @Mergedtable = @MTDResults + @Top10CustMTD`.  `&` is not valid for string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

`&` in TSQL is, unlike Visual Basic, used for boolean operations, not for varchar concatenations. For it, you should use `+`, providing that both of the entries are varchars:

```
set @Mergedtable = @MTDResults + @Top10CustMTD
```

If one of them is not varchar, you will first have to convert it to varchar (not your case, just for future reference):

```
set @Mergedtable = @MTDResults + convert(varchar(max),@Top10CustMTD)
```

For more info on how `&` is used, see [Ampersand (&) operator in a SQL Server WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670230/ampersand-operator-in-a-sql-server-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tomas. That fixed it for me.

set @Mergedtable = @MTDResults + @Top10CustMTD