# SQL Integer and '&' sign

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is somebody able to explain what the below query is actually doing?

```
SELECT (Convert(int, 33558529) & 4096),((Convert(int, 33558529) & 1048576))
FROM dbo.example
```

Why does the first part return 4096 and the second part returns 0?

Comment: The & is a logical "and" bitwise operation. It's behaviour is documented in MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174965.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: what do you want to get from this query ? Here if you enter 1048577 instead of 1048576 than it will return 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` sign in T-SQL is the [bitwise AND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174965.aspx). It is used for bitwise comparison on numbers.

> Why does the first part return 4096 and the second part returns 0?

Because the big number (`33558529`) includes the 4096 bit, but does not contain the 1048576 bit.

---

I find it easier to understand when you use smaller numbers, and write it out in binary. Suppose the big number you're checking is actually 9, written as binary 9 is

```
8 4 2 1
=======
1 0 0 1  <-- 9
```

If we were to perform bitwise AND logic on the above with the number 8 we would get

```
8 4 2 1
=======
1 0 0 1    <-- 9
1 0 0 0    <-- 8
-------
1 0 0 0  < -- result of ANDing 9 & 8 = 8
```

If we did the same exercise but with 2

```
8 4 2 1
=======
1 0 0 1    <-- 9
0 0 1 0    <-- 2
-------
0 0 0 0    <-- result of ANDing 9 & 2 = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

`&` performs a bitwise logical AND operation between two integer values.  See the [doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276873%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Here are the integer values converted to binary :

```
33558529 = 10000000000001000000000001
    4096 =              1000000000000 1 bit match hence 1000000000000 or 4096
 1048576 =      100000000000000000000 0 bit match hence 0
```

Answer (score 0):

> `&` is the bitwise logical and operator - It performs the operation on
>   2 integer values.

Please refer :
[Ampersand (&) operator in a SQL Server WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670230/ampersand-operator-in-a-sql-server-where-clause)

```
SELECT 
(Convert(int, 33558529) & 4096),((Convert(int, 33558529) & 1048576))
FROM dbo.example
```

Its compare the bitwise data and gives the result

Check this [link](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_unsigned_int.html?decimal=051051053053056053050057) and compare the bit value

```
 33558529  - 00000010 00000000 00010000 00000001  
 4096      - 00000000 00000000 00010000 00000000 means 1
 1048576   - 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Same you check the logic behind.