# How to select rows with int flag in doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I would like to use the `Doctrine` query builder to select all entries from a table, that have set a special flag in an `int` column:

```
'query_builder' => $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('e')
    ->from('AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity', 'e')
    ->where('e.flags & 1 = 1');
```

When being used directly in `MySQL`, the `SELECT ... WHERE flags & 1 = 1` syntax works fine. But when trying to execute the above query, I get the following error:

> Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '&'

So how, to handle/select flags using Doctrine?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670230/ampersand-operator-in-a-sql-server-where-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine's syntax is a little bit different. Also the operation you are trying to do is called BITWISE AND Operation.

Try this instead:

```
'query_builder' => $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
->select('e')
->from('AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity', 'e')
->where('BIT_AND(e.flags,1) = 1');
```

Tested on sql server.

Docs: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#id3