# Mean of "&" operator in Where condition in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

What is the mean of below Query in `MySql`, I mean i want to know the use of **`&`** operator in Where condition --->

```
Select * from tbl where Column_Name & 1=1
```

Comment: This is checking `Column_Name` to see if it is an odd number (assuming it's a numeric type; if not, it doesn't make any sense).  Check the duplicate link for more information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670230/ampersand-operator-in-a-sql-server-where-clause

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hats Off to You..!! `Super Like`

Comment: @SagarGangwal We could have answered this one, but it is very close to the duplicate, hence I decided to mark it as such.